Finding a pair values from Array getting more length of pairs
I would like to find the pair of array values which produces multiple of 3 from the array given, as per given array I got the possible of following when I iterate single time. I am trying to achieve the same. but getting more vales. so finding the correct way to achieve the following:
  1. 1+2 = 3
  2. 1+2 = 3
  3. 3+6 = 9
  4. 2+1 = 3
  5. 1+2 = 3

for I try like this:


const ar = [1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2], n = 6, k = 3;
    const list = [];
    
    const filter = (num) => {
      const v = ar.filter(v => {
        if((num+v) %3 === 0){
          list.push([num, v]);
        }
      });
    
    }
    
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      const val = ar[i]
      filter(val)
    }
    
   console.log(list); 



But gives more pairs[12] than required length. How to handle this? I understood I lost some logic here.

Hi! Could you update your post? Not really sure what you want to happen here.

your looping the array then, looping it again to produce the result. So the results are correct. It would be super helpful to explain what you were trying to do, cause that is the correct result of your logic. Filter doesn't look like the right method for your purposes, but who knows what they are. in the 36 iterations there are 12 matches.

I am looking my result should be [[1+2]   [1+2]   [3+6]   [2+1 ]  [1+2]]

You haven't even mentioned anything related to multiples of 3 in the body of your question, so it's really unclear what you're after. Please give a clear statement of your problem in text form, instead of requiring others to guess what you try to do from your examples and incorrect code.

As per the code it completely works fine, but looking as your statement it feels like you want to check this multiple of 3 from the selected index to the index greater that it and not the indexes smaller than or equal to it.

@YashMaheshwari, yes. for me I am getting more arrays than what I need.

Just pass another value as index to the filter function by incrementing it by 1 so that it will check the multiples from the next number and will not include the numbers below the current selected one.


const ar = [1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2], n = 6, k = 3;
const list = [];
    
const filter = (num, index) => {
  for(let i = index; i < n; i++) {
    if((num+ar[i]) %3 === 0){
      list.push([num, ar[i]]);
    }
  }
}
    
for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  const val = ar[i]
  filter(val, i+1)
}
    
console.log(list); 




I tried with this approach. it works better for me.


const ar = [1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2]
const copy = [...ar];
const result = []
ar.forEach(v => {
  copy.shift()
  copy.forEach(n => {
    if((v+n) % 3 === 0) {
      result.push([v,n])
    }
  });
});

console.log(result)



